# Create two level dataset array from Matlab Statistics Toolbox

Tags: matlab, dataset, initialization

I want to create a dataset object from the Matlab Statistics Toolbox as follows:

```
test_dataset = dataset;
test_dataset.level1.level2A = 'foo';
test_dataset.level1.level2B = 'bar';
```

However, Matlab cannot apparently create two new levels to the dataset simultaneously - how do I do this properly?

Many thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you need two levels?  What does having two levels accomplish for you that having a single level with two different names doesn't accomplish?  i.e. level1Level2A instead of level1Level2B?  Sorry, this dataset stuff is new to me.  But very interesting.

Comment: I need two levels, since I have many observations of type "level1" i.e. with two datasets. Then I want a container for such "level1" type of observations. I solved this by using a struct "test_struct.level1A.level2A = dataset" etc.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. For me, I can generate a 2-level [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html). Or is `test_dataset.level1.level2A` something else?

Comment: I was too obsessed by the idea of the new datatype 'dataset' that I wanted to use it everywhere, but as you say, it is not probably wise to use datasets with many levels, as maybe struct is more flexible for that, or at least in my solution, using dataset for the upper most level container makes no apparent sense.

Comment: @Schorsch: Yes, thank you. I used struct. Problem solved.